# Laravel showing unexpected result, may be caching issue

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have application made in Laravel http://maingolf.co.id/, I am facing issue with single-listing page with shows result of single product. When I visit this link (http://maingolf.co.id/listings/modern-golf-tangerang/1) is shows something else and when I hard refresh this page it shows proper result.

It only displays proper result with hard refresh, maybe it is caching issue or issue in router. This is my live site.

Comment: Worth a read: [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428/472495).

Comment: Please add some code. We can't magically know your code and what's wrong with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess, in your database, there is no record related `"id"= 1`, you need verify there is a record in your information table before outputting it.

If you try:

> http://maingolf.co.id/listings/modern-golf-tangerang/2

You will see that there is no record.

Alternatively, it might be cache issue, `Cache::flush()`, try this to see if it works.